# Impersonating jar files of a RCP Application. What factors may make it go wrong?

Tags: java, jar, jvm, eclipse-rcp, aspectj

I was wondering whether it was possible to, given a RCP application, with all its plugin structure, switch some of its original jar files by other bytecode modified by me.

I tried to hack with AspectJ a SWT jar file named `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.6.0.v3650b__________________.jar` and to put it in a hello world SWT application. It worked fine (I did have to delete all its digest messages and CRCs and the like, though).

When attempting to do the same to this big RCP application, it failed, though. I don't exactly why other than it was by the jar file switch. The application just unexpectedly closes.

I'd like to hear cues that could lead to me to the right track, as I'm curious why the Hello World SWT application worked and this other RCP didn't!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at equinox weaving and its use in AJDT and SalaIDE through JDT weaving.  Equinox weaving provides load-time weaving for AspectJ in an OSGi environment.  And JDT weaving is how the two language IDEs use EW to alter behavior inside of Eclipse.

[Equinox Weaving](http://eclipse.org/equinox/weaving/)

[JDT Weaving](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_weaving_features)

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. Does this work even without the original source code?

Comment: Yes. And it can be installed into existing Eclipse/OSGi applicaitons without their needing to upgrade any existing bundles.  Only problem with not have existing source is that it is harder for you to implement (since it is harder to determine join points).

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Meanwhile, what would you guess could be the reason my endeavor failed?

Comment: Not sure what is going on.  A little more context would help.  In theory, you should be able to swap jars in an RCP app as long as the jars have the same name and the bundle ID is the same.  If the jars are signed, this could cause some problems, but not otherwise.

Comment: So, can you provide more info? Any error messages? Are all bundle names the same? Is anything signed? Are you sure your pointcuts are being hit?

Comment: The application unexpectedly closes. I don't understand much about signing, but I guess the file is signed, at least it had files digests (which I deleted).

Comment: Any errors in error log?  What about in the configuration directory? Error logs from the OSGi framework appear there.  I'm guessing that since you are weaving into the swt bundle, there is something that is not being added to the new jar.